# Synology NAS (DSM 5) cannot access the Internet through Tomato router?

Tags: networking, router, nas, tomato, synology

I have just revived my *Linksys* *E3200* router by upgrading it to *Tomato 1.28* (*Shibby*). I have a *Synology* NAS running *DSM 5* attached by cable to the router.

After the upgrade my NAS can no longer update the time or check for DSM updates. It seems like it does not have outgoing access any more.

- I can access the administration module without problems.
- I can access the contents of the NAS from the inside of my network without problems.

The *Default Gateway* of the NAS points to the router.

I don't need external access to the NAS from WAN. I just want to regain outgoing access from the NAS.

**Question:**
What do I need to configure to enable outgoing access from my NAS?

Comment: You said you've checked the Default Gateway setting. What about the DNS servers?

Comment: I have tried setting the DNS manually to the address of the router and it didn't work.

Comment: Try using alternative DNS IPs: `208.67.222.222` `208.67.220.220` (these are OpenDNS' btw).

Comment: I have tried the DNS `208.67.222.222` and it did not work. I can see in the router log that I now get outgoing accepted requests to that DNS address from the NAS.

Comment: Update your post to include your router log. Unless you've made any changes to your NAS recently, Tomato sounds like the culprit. Go to its web management portal, and see if you can find anything that could be causing this issue (sorry, I'm not familiar with it).